# trying to manipulate data for bar chart in python for test scores

Tags: python, django

trying to manipulate data for bar chart in python for test scores for the x-axis we have 0--100 % steps of 9 so if a user scores 4 it will be in the step 0 --9 , if another scores 3 it will be counted as 2 persons scored within the step. any help in implementing this will be appreciated. thanks

```
score = {"0 - 10": 0, "11 - 20": 0, "21 - 30": 0, "31 - 40": 0, "41 - 50": 0,
         "51 - 60": 0, "61 - 70": 0, "71 - 80": 0, "81 - 90": 0,
         "91 - 100": 0}

OUTCOMES = {}
for i in range(0, 10):
    OUTCOMES[i] = score["0 - 10"] = + 1
for i in range(11, 20):
    OUTCOMES[i] = score["11 - 20"] = + 1
for i in range(21, 30):
    OUTCOMES[i] = score["21 - 30"] = + 1
for i in range(31, 40):
    OUTCOMES[i] = score["31 - 40"] = + 1
for i in range(41, 50):
    OUTCOMES[i] = score["41 - 50"] = + 1
for i in range(51, 60):
    OUTCOMES[i] = score["51 - 60"] = + 1
for i in range(61, 70):
    OUTCOMES[i] = score["61 - 70"] = + 1
for i in range(71, 80):
    OUTCOMES[i] = score["71 - 80"] = + 1
for i in range(81, 90):
    OUTCOMES[i] = score["81 - 90"] = + 1
for i in range(91, 100):
    OUTCOMES[i] = score["91 - 100"] = + 1
```

Comment: It is always useful to include a Minimum, Reproducable Example for us to see what you have tried to do. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: what do you want to increase, the score values or the outcome values?

Comment: the score value based on the number of persons that score within a score range,and if there is a more better way to go about this

Comment: but where do you know the nr of people scoring then?

Comment: so the outcome is suppose to check the input and auto increment based on the user score then update the score dic

Comment: okay, so the outcomes' keys are scores from 0-100 and the values are the number of people, so an integer?

Answer (score 1):

By default any key will return 0:

```
OUTCOMES = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
[... fill outcomes dict]
```

So when you increase the score dict's values, it won't fail on any score:

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    score["0 - 10"] += OUTCOMES[i]
```

Additionally, you could simplify the expression by a range map:

```
RANGES = {
    "0 - 10": range(10),
    "10 - 20": range(10, 20),
    ...
}
```

So you new expression could be:

```
for rg in RANGES:
    rg_obj = RANGES[rg]
    score[rg] += sum([OUTCOMES[ix] for ix in rg_obj])
```

Answer (score 0):

As an example, you can use `defaultdict` as a handy accumulator for bar counts:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def get_slot(x):
    """Maps value to bin name"""
    tens = (x-1)//10
    return f'{tens*10+1} - {(tens+1)*10}'

# Empty dictionary with default values equal to zero
counts = defaultdict(int)

# example input data and usage
scores = [1, 2, 7, 15, 16, 30, 80]
for value in scores:
    counts[get_slot(value)] += 1

print(counts)
# Outputs:
# defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'1 - 10': 3, '11 - 20': 2, '21 - 30': 1, '71 - 80': 1})
```

Note, that your bar slots are not equal. The first one (0-10) contains more values, comparing to the rest. Hence my example will put 0 and 1-10 into different slots. If you wish to combine them, you could add `if` check against zero input in the `get_slot` function.